# How to add a submenu to a menu of a theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a total beginner on the platform wordpress ... bought a theme, installed it, everything right, the menus appeared. But I would like to include a submenu, the parent menus in a theme and create a page to add.

How do I do that? 
I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so on your dashboard you see the main menu down the left hand side. The editor for menus is under **Appearance -> Menus**.

In there you should be able to easily structure your menus and sub-menus with a simple drag and drop editor, as long as your theme supports editable menus and sub-menus.

As for creating pages, you do that by going to **Pages -> Add New**. Once you have created a page it should show up in the menu editor to be added.

Hope that helps.